# Is it possible to use passport.js to authenticate wep apis in node?

Tags: node.js, authentication, asp.net-web-api, react-native, passport.js

I am currently using Passport.js as a middleware authentication for my Node.js website. However, I want to use the same authentication services for a react-native application.

Is there a way to expose the generated token by Passport.Js and return it using Json to my react-native app? I know, so far, that it is possible to customize the return of an authentication call such as in

```
  app.post('/api/login',
    function(req, res, next) {
        app.passport.authenticate('login', function(err, user, info) {
            if (err) {
                res.json(200, app.infra.errorReturn('Server error', err, null));
            } else if (user === false) {
                res.json(200, app.infra.errorReturn('Invalid Login', '', null));
            } else {
                res.json(200, app.infra.successReturn('', '', user));
            }
        })(req, res, next);
    });
```

As for the strategy, I am using the LocalStrategy and it is configured like this:

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
app.passport.use('login',
    new LocalStrategy({ passReqToCallback: true },
        function(req, username, password, done) { ....
```

Is this in the "info" parameter? Can it be extracted in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... to make a long story short, I discovered that I could use two (or more) authentication strategies for the same application. One for the routes to pages and another one for the routes comprising the api.

Therefore I managed to solve my own problem by implementing passport-jwt and then using jsonwebtoken in order to generate an "internal" webtoken to be used by the website when accessing the api services.